# I keep pulling/getting pain in the same muscle even when I don't exercise it

Tags: muscle, injury, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery

I pulled a muscle directly under my shoulder blade (dorsal muscles?) a couple of months ago while carrying something heavy - not as I picked it up but as I was walking with it, I felt the muscle "go".
It recovered well but since then about once a week that muscle will spontaneously start to hurt, as if it has been pulled again. Often, I'm not doing *anything* at the time, I can just be sitting there and suddenly it "goes" again. When it is not sore, I can exercise just fine (pull-ups, press ups, etc, not heavy weights) and this doesn't seem to trigger it.

Often, the pain will suddenly stop just as suddenly, rather than gradually fade.

I assume I've hurt the muscle in the original pull but should I do anything about it? Or is it just taking a long time to heal?

Comment: Have you considered visiting a doctor to make sure what the problem is?

Comment: I have considered it, but I wish to have some idea first.

Comment: A couple of months is a fairly long time for a muscle to heal from a strain. It could be connective tissue related; you're a good candidate for medical evaluation.

Comment: I think Eric is right. Go see some expert. And get well soon!

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend an expert to look at it. I would probably start with a PT instead of a doctor, but either should work.

Back muscles are weird. You can have cases where a muscle is persistently tight but not painful, and then some occurrence will trigger it to get painful. The fix will likely be some combination of massage, pressure-point therapy, ultrasound, stretching, and exercise.